# How do I decode FAA SNOWTAMs?

Tags: snowtam

[New FAA Notam site](https://notams.aim.faa.gov/notamSearch/nsapp.html#/) marks certain notams as Snowtam and provides Runway Condition. I can decode `E)` part using [FAA Runway Condition](https://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Notice/N_JO_7930.107_Field_Condition_(FICON)_Reporting.pdf). But how can I decode the Q section. Is there a comprehensive source for decoding Notams?

FAA publishes same notam in 2 different formats. I am interested in decoding ICAO Format.

ICAO FORMAT:

```
12/057 NOTAMN  Q) ZBW/QMRXX/IV/NBO/A/000/999/4221N07100W005  
  A) KBOS  B) 1912310152  C) 2001010152   
  E) 09 FICON 5/5/5 100 PCT WET  OBS AT 1912310152.
```

DOMESTIC FORMAT:

```
!BOS 12/057 BOS RWY 09 FICON 5/5/5 100 PCT WET OBS AT 1912310152. 1912310152-2001010152
```

Comment: [ICAO Annex 15](https://www.skybrary.aero/bookshelf/books/2361.pdf)

Comment: This is FAA's runway condition format, which is different than the one used in Europe i assume. So ICAO Annex 15 does not seem to fit into this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, a SNOWTAM actually has a different format, and your example is just a standard NOTAM in ICAO format.

```
12/057 NOTAMN  Q) ZBW/QMRXX/IV/NBO/A/000/999/4221N07100W005     
  A) KBOS  B) 1912310152  C) 2001010152      
  E) 09 FICON 5/5/5 100 PCT WET OBS AT 1912310152.
```

This decodes into the following:

```
Series and number:        12/057
Nature of the NOTAM:      New (N in the NOTAMN)

Q) Qualifier line:  
   FIR:                   Boston FIR (ZBW)
   NOTAM Code:            Starts with Q and the following four letters:
                          Subject: Runway (MR)  
                          Condition: Not Specified / Plain Language (XX)  
   Traffic:               NOTAM issued for IFR (I) flights and VFR flights (V)  
   Purpose:               NOTAM selected for immediate attention of flight crew members (N), 
                          for PIB entry (B), and concerning flight operations (O)  
   Scope:                 Aerodrome (A)  
   Limits:                FL 000 to FL 999 (000/999)  
   Geographical location: 42°21' N 071° 100' W (4221N07100W)
                          Operation radius of the NOTAM: 5 NM (005)  

A) Aerodrome:             Boston Logan (KBOS)  
B) From:                  01:52 UTC 31 December 2019 (191231 0152)  
C) Until:                 01:52 UTC 01 January 2020 (200101 0152)  
E) Text of the NOTAM:     Runway 09 Field Condition
                          Braking action 5/5/5 (good for each third of the runway), 
                          Runway is 100% wet
                          Observed at 0152 UTC on 31 December 2019
```

We could dig into the ICAO documents to find the official guidance, but different countries implement it differently sometimes anyway.  [Here's](http://vat-air.dk/files/ICAO%20NOTAM%20format.pdf) a good document that I found which breaks down the different codes.